# How to correctly convert 999999999.99999999 to integer

Tags: go

I have a float number 999999999.99999999 and I will want to convert float to integer number. 
I expect result 99999999999999999 but got 100000000000000000
Why ?)

```
import (
    "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
    "log"
)

func MultiplyFloatToInt(value float64, multiplier int64) (result int64) {
    return decimal.NewFromFloat(value).Mul(decimal.NewFromFloat(float64(multiplier))).IntPart()
}

func main() {
    bigFloat := float64(999999999.99999999)

    multilayer := float64(100000000)

    log.Println(bigFloat)
    log.Println(int64(bigFloat * multilayer))
    log.Println(MultiplyFloatToInt(bigFloat, int64(multilayer)))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_1rmUkjf9Nr

Comment: after converting to int how you expect this answer `999999999.99999999`

Comment: How can be `999999999.99999999` be an integer?

Comment: There are only 15 significant digits in a double.  Your number has 18 digits so it will round up to the nearest 15.  If you try 15 significant digits, you might get all your 9s.

Comment: Try to understand how floats are represented and that floats are anything but a rational number.

Comment: @Raju Komati thanks, I corected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting any float to an integer will always result in a whole number.  I am not sure if you expected a decimal output, or mistyped your question.

The reason your example rounds upward has been explained in other answers and comments and relates to your input exceeding the precision of a float64.  If you remove one of the nines from your example and replay it, you will see that the value doesn't get rounded upward.

When dealing with numbers outside the limits of float64 you can use the math/big library.

Something like this should give you the result you are expecting.

```
package main

import (
    "math/big"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    bigFloatStr := "999999999.99999999"
    bigFloat, _ := new(big.Float).SetString(bigFloatStr)

    multiplier := new(big.Float).SetInt64(100000000)

    result := new(big.Float)
    result.Mul(bigFloat, multiplier)

    bigInt := new(big.Int)
    result.Int(bigInt)

    intVal := bigInt.Int64()

    log.Println(bigFloat)
    log.Println(result)
    log.Println(bigInt)
    log.Println(intVal) 
}
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 9.9999999999999999e+08
2009/11/10 23:00:00 9.9999999999999999e+16
2009/11/10 23:00:00 99999999999999999
2009/11/10 23:00:00 99999999999999999
```

https://play.golang.org/p/w4fMuPE1ADf

Answer (score 3):

Your title and question body are in contradiction to the code you present. But the issue is down to how you construct the `bigFloat`.

`999999999.99999999` is a `double` constant, but there is no `double` that can model that exact value, so the one closest to it is picked, and that is `100000000`. It doesn't matter that it's passed as an argument to a constructor of an object capable of representing your original number: by then the reversion to the nearest `double` has already taken place.

The normal thing to do here is to use the constructor that takes a string.